# WCF Service -> max

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, web-config

Looks like this question has been asked thousand times already, but each person's configuration problems are different. I have WCF server that serves images and also receives upload image requests. When uploading images I'm getting error 400 when size is more then 65k.

I turned the trace on the WCF and I'm getting exact error

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

I know that I need to increase this parameters but I'm just can find where is it supposed to be in my web.config file. Here is what I have in web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" closeTimeout="04:01:00"
          openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          textEncoding="utf-8"
          transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="returnFaults">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="ESLMobileIhaServiceClient.ServiceMobileIha" behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults">
        <endpoint contract="ESLMobileIhaServiceClient.ServiceMobileIha" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
```

Anyone here whih can help me out with this? ;) trying since 4 hours with different approaches found on stackoverflow but nothing helps - unfortunatelly.

**UPDATE:**

the request is an upload of a file from client TO server. The error appears in the servers logfile when enabled diagnostics.

**SERVER Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" closeTimeout="04:01:00"
          openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          textEncoding="utf-8"
          transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="returnFaults">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="ESLMobileIhaServiceClient.ServiceMobileIha" behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults">
        <endpoint contract="ESLMobileIhaServiceClient.ServiceMobileIha" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Client App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="InputFileLocation" value="U:\vorlagen\esl_evu_demo\Mobile Instandhaltung\Testdaten\Stammdaten\"/>
    <add key="OutputFileLocationOpen" value="U:\vorlagen\esl_evu_demo\Mobile Instandhaltung\Testdaten\offen\"/>
    <add key="OutputFileLocationClosed" value="U:\vorlagen\esl_evu_demo\Mobile Instandhaltung\Testdaten\abgeschlossen\"/>
    <add key="ImageObserveLocation" value="U:\vorlagen\esl_evu_demo\Mobile Instandhaltung\Testdaten\kamerabilder\"/>
    <add key="ImageSaveLocation" value="U:\vorlagen\esl_evu_demo\Mobile Instandhaltung\Testdaten\savedimages\"/>
    <add key="DeleteImageAfterCopy" value="true"/>
    <add key="HelpFile_de_DE" value="ESL_EVU_1031_Mobile_Instandhaltung.pdf"/>
    <add key="HelpFile_fr_FR" value=""/>
    <add key="BackupLocation" value="backup\"/>
    <add key="NumOfBackups" value="3"/>
    <add key="Language" value="de_DE"/>
    <add key="FontType" value="Arial"/>
    <add key="TextSize" value="10"/>
    <add key="TitleTextSize" value="12"/>
    <add key="ButtonTextSize" value="12"/>
    <add key="IdentifikationGeraet" value="Kontrolle/Instandhaltung"/>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ServiceMobileIha" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:51515/ServiceMobileIha.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ServiceMobileIha"
        contract="ServiceReference1.ServiceMobileIha" name="BasicHttpBinding_ServiceMobileIha" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but did you update your client's service reference after you made the change to the maxReceivedMessageSize? Also, are you sure that the web.config you changed is the one being used by your service? How are you hosting the service...verify that your app.config has this same information. In the past, I've changed my web.config, but it's hosted in an app with an app.config and forgot to update that one.

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
```

with

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
```

to allow overall httpRuntime -> maxRequestLenght increase ;)

have a nice weekend guys

Answer (score 0):

It's can be problem of client side. Did you change `maxReceivedMessageSize` , `maxBufferPoolSize` and `maxBufferSize` on your client side?

Comment: as you see in my updated client and server config - its all set to high values ;) even though - it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

This does affect specifically the maxReceivedMessageSize configuration, but it could be client or server. Because the client is receiving the reply, but the server is receiving the request. So it depends which one is too big. For example, if the client is sending the big payload, but the server is sending back void or a bool or something small, it's the server's config that has to change, and vice versa.